# How to make a Pandas Period Index by week

Tags: python, pandas, sktime

I am working on a forecasting model in which I want to use various temporal aggregates of data such as daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, and yearly.

For creating the forecast models, I am using the library `sktime`. For loading the data `sktime` is compatible with `pandas` dataframes. In order to denote the temporal ordering, `sktime` allows the dataframe to be indexed by `PeriodIndex`.

For monthly, quarterly, and yearly granularities I do not have a problem setting up the index since the [PeriodIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) constructor has parameters for year, quarter, month, and day. However, it does not have a parameter for week.

So I am wondering what I am supposed to do to get around this?

To be specific, I am able to get the other aggregates in the following away, and I would have expected to be able to do something similar for week, but alas I cannot.

```
# DAILY
dates = ["01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "25/01/2000", "01/01/3005"]
pd.PeriodIndex(dates, freq='d')

# MONTHLY
pd.PeriodIndex(year=[2000]*12, month=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], freq='w')

# QUARTERLY
pd.PeriodIndex(year=[2000,2000,2000,2000], quarter=[1,2,3,4])

...
```

I assume week is not as straightforward since some years have 52 weeks and others 53.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with the help of Pandas [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.PeriodIndex(
    pd.date_range("01/01/2000", "31/12/2000", freq="w"), freq="W-MON"
)

print(idx)
# Output
PeriodIndex(['1999-12-28/2000-01-03', '2000-01-04/2000-01-10',
             '2000-01-11/2000-01-17', '2000-01-18/2000-01-24',
             '2000-01-25/2000-01-31', '2000-02-01/2000-02-07',
             '2000-02-08/2000-02-14', '2000-02-15/2000-02-21',
             '2000-02-22/2000-02-28', '2000-02-29/2000-03-06',
             '2000-03-07/2000-03-13', '2000-03-14/2000-03-20',
             '2000-03-21/2000-03-27', '2000-03-28/2000-04-03',
             '2000-04-04/2000-04-10', '2000-04-11/2000-04-17',
             '2000-04-18/2000-04-24', '2000-04-25/2000-05-01',
             '2000-05-02/2000-05-08', '2000-05-09/2000-05-15',
             '2000-05-16/2000-05-22', '2000-05-23/2000-05-29',
             '2000-05-30/2000-06-05', '2000-06-06/2000-06-12',
             '2000-06-13/2000-06-19', '2000-06-20/2000-06-26',
             '2000-06-27/2000-07-03', '2000-07-04/2000-07-10',
             '2000-07-11/2000-07-17', '2000-07-18/2000-07-24',
             '2000-07-25/2000-07-31', '2000-08-01/2000-08-07',
             '2000-08-08/2000-08-14', '2000-08-15/2000-08-21',
             '2000-08-22/2000-08-28', '2000-08-29/2000-09-04',
             '2000-09-05/2000-09-11', '2000-09-12/2000-09-18',
             '2000-09-19/2000-09-25', '2000-09-26/2000-10-02',
             '2000-10-03/2000-10-09', '2000-10-10/2000-10-16',
             '2000-10-17/2000-10-23', '2000-10-24/2000-10-30',
             '2000-10-31/2000-11-06', '2000-11-07/2000-11-13',
             '2000-11-14/2000-11-20', '2000-11-21/2000-11-27',
             '2000-11-28/2000-12-04', '2000-12-05/2000-12-11',
             '2000-12-12/2000-12-18', '2000-12-19/2000-12-25',
             '2000-12-26/2001-01-01'],
            dtype='period[W-MON]')
```